# jQuery Ajax URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I am doing an Ajax call from **site.com/users/{username}**

i wanna access the url **site.com/account/deleteComment** but when i check in fireBug it is trying to access **site.com/users/account/deleteComment**

here is my code

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "../account/deleteComment/" + deleteID,
        success: function () {
            $("#comment-" + deleteID).slideUp("fast");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, then `../../` is going to do the trick, isn't it?

That said, it would probably be a good idea to use absolute URLs here.

```
  url: "/account/deleteComment/" + deleteID,
```

this will take away your ability to easily  move your application into a sub-folder, but in most cases, that is not a problem.

Comment: looks like it works. on local host i am having my app at localhost/project/  so its going to localhost/account/deleteComment  is there a way to make it work from any place. i am sure it will work on the server :D

Comment: @Harsha you would have to define the current subdirectory of the application in a central .js file: `rootPath = "http://localhost/project"` and add `rootPath` to every URL you specify.

Answer (score 11):

you can use location.origin for get base address

```js
var deleteID;
 $.ajax({
        url:location.origin + "/account/deleteComment/" + deleteID,
        success: function () {
            $("#comment-" + deleteID).slideUp("fast");
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
 $.ajax({
        url:location.origin + "/account/deleteComment/" + deleteID,
        success: function () {
            $("#comment-" + deleteID).slideUp("fast");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Put me on the right path where I found `window.location.origin` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/origin

Answer (score 2):

Change the URL to:

```
/account/deleteComment/
```

That way it'll go to the root path:

```
site.com/account/deleteComment
```

Answer (score 2):

Absolute URL is a good idea in `ajax` but this is more good and easy way.
Just declared `var siteURL = www.example.com;` globally.
And used this in every `ajax` request like below.

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: siteURL + '/path/to/file',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {param1: 'value1'},
});
</script>
```

Generally, I declared in main index file or config of JS file.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had a similar problem in one of my apps.
The solution I used was

```
$.url("Config/GetEnvironment")
```

Which ever directory I am in the URL is rendered correctly.